# OOP Python Problem - 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, arguments, typeerror

```
class Employees():
    base_salary = 12000

    def __init__(self, f_name: str, l_name: str):
        assert l_name is not str, 'Last name must be a string'
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.l_name = l_name
        self.email = f_name + l_name + '@yokio.com'
class Cleaners(Employees):
    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, hours_worked):
        super().__init__(self, f_name, l_name)
        def get_bonus():
            self.hours_worked = hours_worked
            self.bonus = (self.base_salary * (hours_worked // 730))

            # cleaners have the base salary



worker_1 = Employees('divine', 'jojolola')
print(worker_1.email)
print(worker_1.base_salary)
worker_2 = Cleaners('Joe', 'Boy', 500)
print(worker_2.email)
worker_2.get_bonus()
print(worker_2.get_bonus)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/divine/PycharmProjects/test what i have learnt/oop.py", line 23, in <module>
    worker_2 = Cleaners('Joe', 'Boy', 500)
  File "/Users/divine/PycharmProjects/test what i have learnt/oop.py", line 11, in __init__
    super().__init__(self, f_name, l_name)
TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: You don't explicitly pass self when using super.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being corrected by some superior being, I believe this is the current best practice:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(B, self).__init__(x)
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.x=} {self.y=}'

bc = B(1, 2)

print(bc)
```

**Output:**

```
self.x=1 self.y=2
```

Comment: At the very least, drop the explicit arguments to `super`. ([Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) discusses the merits of replacing positional arguments with keyword augments for `super`, which among other things lets you avoid duplicating parameters like `x`.)

Answer (score -1):

```py
class Employees():
    base_salary = 12000

    def __init__(self, f_name: str, l_name: str):
        assert l_name is not str, 'Last name must be a string'
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.l_name = l_name
        self.email = f_name + l_name + '@yokio.com'
class Cleaners(Employees):
    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, hours_worked,base_salary):
        super().__init__(f_name, l_name)
        self.hours_worked = hours_worked
        self.base_salary=base_salary
          
    def get_bonus(self):
        return self.base_salary * self.hours_worked // 730
        
            # cleaners have the base salary



worker_1 = Employees('divine', 'jojolola')
print(worker_1.email)
print(worker_1.base_salary)
worker_2 = Cleaners('Joe', 'Boy', 500,10000)
print(worker_2.email)
worker_2.get_bonus()
print(worker_2.get_bonus())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).